Does uniform sampling from a sample set preserve its distribution
Given a set of $N$ i.i.d samples $\delta_1, \dots, \delta_N$, where each $\delta_i \sim \mathbb{P}$ is distributed according to some distribution $\mathbb{P}$, i.e., $(\delta_1,\dots,\delta_n) \sim \mathbb{P}^N$.
If we select a subset of size $M \leq N$ of the samples uniformly,  independently of the samples, and without replacement, i.e., every subset has the same probability $p$ to be selected. Are the resulting selected samples still distributed according to $\mathbb{P}$ (or $\mathbb{P}^M$ for the subset)?

Welcome to MSE! Your post doesn’t have some required contexts, such as your trials or any suggestions or possible approaches you’ve done. Please add some of those above to make your post high quality. :)

You may want to say that the subset is selected without replacement.

@Henry Thanks for the comment, I added it to the question!
